# Происхождение поговорки "катись колбаской по Новоспасской"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Есть такая поговорка "Катись колбаской по Новоспасской". А откуда оно пошло?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Имеется в виду Новоспасский мост в Москве. Он был построен в 1911 г. и сильно сократил маршруты из Замоскворечья в Рогожскую слободу, новый на тот момент промышленный район.
При чем тут "колбаска" - наверняка не скажу, но вроде бы колбасками называли трамваи (сцепку из двух и более вагонов).

Кстати, "поговорка" (вернее сказать - прибаутка) существует ещё и в варианте "по Малой Спасской". Что здесь может означать Малая Спасская, ничем не примечательная московская улочка (ныне - 1-й Коптельский переулок), я не скажу. Возможно это был "питерский ответ" москвичам. В Петербурге улица Малая Спасская (ныне - Карбышева) повесомее будет. И по ней, если не ошибаюсь, тоже бегали питерские "колбаски", только автобусы.

~~~

Вот и насчет колбасы нашел подтвержение.

*Катись колбаской по Малой Спасской — известная поговорка, означающая «иди-ка ты отсюда» (или «гуляй, Вася», «скатерью дорожка», «иди к чёрту».*

*Объясняется распространенной среди мальчишек-сорванцов (иногда и более почтенной публики) первой половины XX века привычке бесплатно ездить на сцепке трамвая («на колбасе», как говорили в связи с ее тогдашней трубообразной формой). Иногда поговорку перетолковывают как якобы намек на тонкую колбасу, связанную кольцом, которая может с легкостью катиться. Варианты фразы: «катись колбасой», «катись колбаской».*

*Известно употребление этой фразы в фильмах «Республика ШКИД» и «Мимино», романах Николая Островского «Как закалялась сталь», Фадеева «Разгром» (Разгром) и других произведениях. Фраза часто употребляется в качестве броского заголовка в периодике, а также в рекламе. Фраза «катиться колбасой» иногда употребляется для описания скатывания человека с горки.*

(Словари на "академике", грамматика - оригинальная, похоже с Вики списано. ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Колбасой" называется шланг воздушного тормоза трамвая. Он довольно прочный и за него можно держаться, стоя на подножке или на сцепке.

Comment: Это известно (см. мой ответ). Но вопрос не про колбасу, а про выражение  в целом.